# Sending data from computer to iOS using Core Bluetooth

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

Is it possible to send data from any computer the supports BLE (Windows or Mac) to an iOS app's `CBCentralManager`?

The data I want to send is purely text based. I'm searching for it but I am not being able to find if it is possible or a tutorial of how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, normally you can do that. What you have to do is:

- From the peripheral device (transmitter), advertise an CBService
  (iOS) with a CBCharacteristic that support write value.
- From the receiver, you create a CBCentralManager to search for the service created by the transmitter, then discover the right CBCharacteristic. Once the CBCharacteristic discovered, you can try to write value to that characteristic.

The processus look simple, but you have to do step by step on the receiver's side:

- first, look for device
- if device found, try to connect
- then once connected to that device, try to discover the service
- then once the service discovered, try to discover the characteristic
- then once the characteristic is discovered, try to send
- then you will receive the result of sending (ok or failed)

Take a look at [my project in github](https://github.com/haduyenhoa/BLE-Swift), it's not complete but it show you how to exchange data between 2 BLE devices. The application is for iOS, but I'm pretty sure that you have the same code in Mac OS. I don't know how it works on PC.

Comment: Thank you. So it would only be compatible with a Mac or iOS device that advertises itself as CBPeripheral?

Comment: I think that it should work with all kind of BLE device that advertises an Service with writable Characteristic (or they can use another name). Here is how it works on Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html